# turning bitcoin into cash like euro,usd,peso etc.currency

Tags: sell-bitcoins

how can you turn bitcoin like any currency into a cash hand,where you can exchange bitcoin and turn into normal currency in your hand.my friend has a bitcoin dont know how to make as cash on hand